# Does it seem from NAT when they really come through a proxy?

Tags: proxy, ip, nat

Just question.
When a client really come through a proxy, can we tell it from being through NAT?

Comment: Maybe. Same proxy servers will add an X-Forwarded-For header to each HTTP request they relay. The proxy server maybe behind a NAT device as well and off-hand I don't know a way to distinguish that.

Comment: Thanks for a useful point. Im sure the case with through both NAT & proxy should be thought. X-forward-for header is one of clues, but not all is the case including it in  headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, non-transparent proxy inserts "Via:" field to HTTP request header.

Of course, this is configurable option that can be disabled,
for example: http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/via/

Transparent proxy tries to be invisible, so cannot be detected:

> "A 'transparent proxy' is a proxy that does not modify the request or
>   response beyond what is required for proxy authentication and
>   identification".

See here for more info: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server#Transparent_proxy

Answer (score 2):

A silent proxy may be indistinguishable from NAT. But some may add headers, that allow to identify that request comes through proxy.

Comment: If in a situation that enable you to add some headers yourself, you can guess of it. That's a useful point. Thanks.